# mimicking make dependency checking in perl

Tags: perl, makefile

Not sure if I am explaining this well, but here goes...

I have a perl script/flow that runs various steps. Each step is basically dependent on the output of its previous step in order to run.

For example:

```
myflow -step1...input is file0, produces file1
myflow -step2...input is file1, produces file2
myflow -stepN...input is fileN-1, produces fileN
```

Right now users can run myflow `-step1 -step2...-stepN` to go from start to finish. I would like to somehow have the ability for the user to run myflow `-stepN`, have myflow check to see which steps need to be run prior to it, and then run `stepN`. Maybe no steps were run, so myflow `-stepN` would start from `step1` and continue until it finishes `stepN` or an error occurs. Maybe `step1` through `step3` ran fine previously, so running `-stepN` would start from `step4`. Maybe all steps ran fine, but the user modified/deleted/touched an intermediate file, so running `-stepN` would detect this and rerun from that previous step.

Is there a cpan module that essentially mimics this make behavior, i.e. given steps, inputs they require, and outputs they produce, create a dependency graph and determine which steps need to be run?

Comment: How is the status of each step stored?

Comment: for first round step status will just be existence of output files...if they are present, then i will consider it passed, else failed.  next phase would be to write out some status file which states pass or error or waived.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could use `make` itself instead of trying to simulate it.

The makefile rules for "building" each `fileX` "target" from the `fileX-1` "source file" would be invoking your script for the respective step.